# Elasticsearch With Node.js throwing an Error: connect EADDRNOTAVAIL

Tags: node.js, docker, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch6.8.3 docker on an AWS ec2 machine for the production environment. For this purpose, I have installed Elasticsearch via docker-compose. In a microservice architecture many of the other services using different languages like PHP and Python, are just working fine. But When it comes to the Node.js client it starts throwing this error:

```
Connect EADDRNOTAVAIL IP_ADDRESS:9200 - Local (IP_ADDRESS:0)
at onResponse (/var/app/current/node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/Transport.js:228:13)
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> 
(/var/app/current/node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/Connection.js:113:9)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:314:20)
at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:427:9)
at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

I have also verified the docker container is up and running at that time, as it was accessible through the web browser. I am not sure about the problem that is it a Node client issue or there is something wrong with docker networking? Also right after restarting the docker container, everything started working

Comment: can you please check elasticsearch log while this error is occuring?

Comment: @SagarPatel it saying: org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: all shards failed

Comment: can you please put here your index configuration ? how many shards and replicas you have configured ? what is your cluster size - how many nodes you have in cluster ?

Comment: @SagarPatel  number_of_nodes:1 , active_primary_shards:39, unassigned_shards:33 replicas:0